# Can't connect client to server in Python 3.6.4

Tags: network-programming, python-3.6

Server Code:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Client Code:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("localhost", 8000)
conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
```

I get ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)
error on client side, and code 400, message Bad request version on server side. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: You are connecting a **TLS** client to a **TCP** server, how do you think they could interoperate? They can not, so you need to use TCP on both sides or TLS on both sides.